# Saving a value to and reading from the viewstate

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate, webforms

I'm not too familiar with .NET, but I want to save a simple value (a number between 1 and 1000, which is the height of a particular `div`) to the viewstate and retrieve it when the update panel reloads (either in the markup somewhere or with javascript). What is the simplest way to do this?

[This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287536%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) gives me the following code:

```
string strColor;
if (Page.IsPostBack)
{
   // Retrieve and display the property value.
   strColor = (string)ViewState["color"];
   Response.Write(strColor);
}
else
   // Save the property value.
   ViewState["color"] = "yellow";
```

However, I'm not totally clear on where or how to access the example strColor.

Since this is in the code behind, where will `Response.Write` even spit that code out? I couldn't find it when I tried this code. And how do I use javascript to set that value, instead of setting it in the code behind?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply set the div as a server control as so:

```
<div id="yourdiv" runat="server" ...
```

And when the page posts back; simply set it's height by setting its attributes; for example:

```
yourDiv.Attributes("style","height:"+height_read_from_ViewState+"px;");
```

Or, you can store the height on the client side, using a Hidden field and reading that hidden field's value on the server side to set the div's height.

```
<asp:hiddenfield id="hdnHeight" runat="server" />
```

You set the height in Javascript as so:

```
function setHeight(value)
{
  document.getElementById('<%=hdnHeight.ClientID').value=value;
}
```

And on post back on server side:

```
yourDiv.Attributes("style","height:"+hdnHeight.Value+"px;");
```

Comment: This is super helpful--I'm sorry I'm so new at this, but it isn't obvious to me how to make the hidden field keep its value through postback. I've created the hidden field and I'm keeping it's value updated with javascript. So if the div height is 30, the hidden field is 30, but then on reload, the hidden field is null again. What am I missing?

Edit:--whoops! Sorry, it does it automatically. I must have had a cache problem. This works perfectly, thanks!!

Comment: You are not missing anything. If the page is reloaded, as in "typing the url and hitting enter" then it's normal that the value is reset because you are coming to the page for the first time. If you are talking about a postback (i.e. clicking on a button on the page and submitting the form) then the value in the hidden field should be preserved because the ViewState will preserve it for you. Is that -the ladder- what's happening to you?

Comment: You're right: I was confused because I was reloading instead of doing the postback thing. To have the value persist through a reload, I guess I'd need to save something on the server--not worth my effort right now since the main thing I need is for it to persist through postback, so it works now, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I would change strColor to a property and use the viewstate as a backing store for the propery.

```
public string strColor 
{
    get
    {
        return ViewState["strColor"];
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["strColor"] = value;
    }

}
```

And then you would use it like any other property:

```
if (Page.IsPostBack)
{
   // Retrieve and display the property value.
   Response.Write(strColor);
}
else
   // Save the property value.
   strColor = "yellow";
```

Comment: Cool. So how can I set the strColor to something besides 'yellow'? I'd like to set it to the height of a div--would it help if I dynamically populated a hidden text input?

Comment: You can use it like a normal variable, wherever normal variables can be used. I dont really understand your context so I cant give a recommendation on anything more than your original question.

Comment: Let me put it this way: say I don't want to save `strColor` to 'yellow' but to a value that the user inputs when prompted with a javascript prompt. How can I set `strColor` to the user's response with javascript?

Comment: Ahhh, ok. Add a `<asp:HiddenField/>` to the page and use JavaScript to set the hidden field's value to the user response. `HiddenField` has ViewState built in so you wouldnt my code. Basically, Icarus' response.

Comment: I agree that encapsulating your ViewState variables into properties makes it easier to access them, but is this considered best practice? Is there anything written about this online that would help me make the case to implement this as a standard? I can't seem to find any article specifically referring to the benefits of this practice...

Comment: @Dave13s Are you concerned about best practices for storing data in the viewstate or best practices for accessing the viewstate? If the later, I know of no reason why you shouldnt use this syntax. If the former, then I'm afraid that I am too far away from the ASP.NET to meaningfully answer this comment for today's environments.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear, I meant to ask weather you had any documentation referring to the practice of encapsulating your view-state variables within properties, rather than accessing them directly in code. But I think I've already found something that will work: https://www.sitepoint.com/premium/books/the-asp-net-2-0-anthology-101-essential-tips-tricks-hacks/preview/what-s-the-cleanest-way-to-access-a-page-s-view-state-0d1cbaf