# How to update ASP Web application Literal or Label after user presses button

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Warning: I am a novice when it comes to ASP and javascript - I'm more used to desktop apps. Web development is completely new to me.

I have inherited an ASP.net project that I need to keep up-to-date.

My current problem is that I need to display the client time in a text control (label or literal control - doesn't have to specifically be one of those, I just need to show it in text) when the user has clicked a button to 'Save'. If I do it server-side, in the 'SaveChanges' function, I get the time of where the server is.

My button is defined as below:

```
<asp:Button ID="Save" runat="server" Text="Save Changes" OnClick="SaveChanges" 
 ValidationGroup="ProjectSummaryValidationGroup" 
 meta:resourcekey="SaveResource1" />
```

And my Literal/Label is:

```
<asp:Label ID="SaveTime" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

I have found a javascript function to calculate the client time from one of the other questions on here: (EDIT: I have updated this function so that the text value of my label is being assigned a value)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function GetDate(date) {
  CurTime = new Date(date);
  var offset = (new Date().getTimezoneOffset() / 60) * (-1);
  var utc = CurTime.getTime() + (offset * 60000 * (-1));
  var serverDate = new Date(utc + (3600000 * offset));
  var dateString = (serverDate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + serverDate.getDate() + "/" +
  serverDate.getFullYear() + " " + serverDate.toLocaleTimeString("en-US", { hour12: true });

  document.getElementById('<%=SaveTime.ClientID%>').Text = dateString;
 }
</script>
```

My problem is I don't know where to put this javascript function in my apsx page, or how to set the Text value of my label to the date string calculated in the function. I don't even know for sure how to 'call' this function...

So my questions are:

1. Where do I have to define the javascript function?
2. How to I 'call' this javascript function when the user clicks the 'Save' button, so that the text one my age is updated?

Comment: I have posted answer try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Java Script Function like

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function javascriptFunction()
{

}
</script>
```

call this function 
If you Used Update Panels Then You can Use in .Cs Page:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "javascriptFunction();", true);
```

or On Button's Click in .aspx page

```
<asp:Button ID="Save" runat="server" Text="Save Changes" OnClick="SaveChanges" 
onClientClick="javascriptFunction();"
 ValidationGroup="ProjectSummaryValidationGroup" 
 meta:resourcekey="SaveResource1" />
```

Other Wise You can Use in .cs page

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript
        (GetType(),Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "javascriptFunction();",true);
```

set value of Label in javascript:

```
document.getElementById('<%=SaveTime.ClientID%>').value = "Your Date";
```

for label :

```
void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
      lblMyLabel.Attributes.Add("onclick",
           "javascript:alert('ALERT ALERT!!!')");
}
```

Comment: Thanks. 
I have tried the 'OnClientClick' suggestion you have posted, but the label doesn't show (edit: doesn't show the text). Where exactly does the function have to be declared? Is anywhere on the same page sufficient?

Comment: `OnClientClick' only for button. calling javascript from label click i updated my answer

Comment: Ganesh, yes I know 'OnClientClick' is just for the button. I want the text to show when the user clicks the button, but when I set the value for the button 'OnClientClick=GetDate()" the text isn't being updated.. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: simply check whether in `alert(dateString)` you are getting right result or not in javascript before `document.getElementById('<%=SaveTime.ClientID%>').Text = dateString;`

Comment: Hi Ganesh, I am getting the correct result and can see this using 'alert(dateString)', and I am also getting the correct result when I use 'alert(document.getElementById('<%=SaveTime.ClientID%>').Text)' after assigning it the value. However, the label is still not being updated on the page. If I debug into the code-behind, the 'Text' value of the 'SaveTime' control is empty.

Comment: After messing around a bit, I've noticed that when I click the 'SaveChanges' button, it calls javascript function (assigned to 'OnClientClick') and shows the alerts, and then it calls the 'Load_Page' function before calling the 'SaveChanges' function. Could it be possible that the text value I am assigning in my GetDate() function is being lost because of this?

Comment: :) save values in Hidder fields, use this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11782654/saving-a-value-to-and-reading-from-the-viewstate

Comment: Thanks for your help, Ganesh. I am having the same problem with the HiddenField. The value of the hidden field is not being kept and is always empty when I try to access it in code-behind after clicking 'SaveChanges'...

Comment: otherwise use Session["key"]

Comment: Wow, I am getting it to work now. In my javascript function I was using '.Value' to assign the hidden field. It should have been '.value', with a lower case 'v'. Many thanks for your help Ganesh!